# How do I implement a Sequalize API into my React application?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I want to be able to get the records from my MYSQL database into my API but I do not know how to route it (do I need to create a component?). I couldn't find any resources about using sequelize with React so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var db = require("../models");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get("/api/teams", function(req, res) {
    var query = {};
    if (req.query.team_id) {
      query.team_id = req.query.team_id;
    } else if (req.query.team_name) {
      query.team_name = req.query.team_name;
    } else if (req.query.logo_link) {
      query.logo_link = req.query.logo_link;
    }

db.Team.findAll({
  where: query
}).then(function(dbEvent) {
  console.log(dbEvent);
  res.json(dbEvent);
});
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You create APIs and then you consume it within your react App. Since you have included tag `express`. This is the way to go.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const db = require("../models");

app.get('/api/teams', async (req, res) => {
  const query = {};
    if (req.query.team_id) {
      query.team_id = req.query.team_id;
    } else if (req.query.team_name) {
      query.team_name = req.query.team_name;
    } else if (req.query.logo_link) {
      query.logo_link = req.query.logo_link;
    }

   db.Team.findAll({
     where: query
    }).then(function(dbEvent) {
     console.log(dbEvent);
    res.json(dbEvent);
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: How do I consume this within my react app? Do you mind explaining?

Comment: Making http requests.

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize is a serverside library. It is not supposed to be used with React because React is a clientside library for the browser. Your code snippet doesn't give me enough info to give you a working solution, but, I will try to help give a general answer to your question:

Your React app is **clientside** code that will execute on a web browser, alongside html and css. This is where your UI lives.

Your Sequelize implementation will probably be part of a **serverside** Node.js app. Your clientside app will make *get* and *post* requests to your serverside app's different routes.

The MySQL **Database** you have set up will be called by your serverside application. Each route on your server will run a different sequelize query on your database. When the query is done, it passes the result back to server, which sends the result back to the client.

---

By the sounds of your question, it sounds like you are mixing up clientside code and serverside code. **Clientside React code never talks to the database. You need to create a Serverside app with APIs/Routes (and Sequelize if you want to use it) to do that.**

Client ----HTTP Request----> Server ----Sql/Sequelize Query----> Database

Client <---- HTTP Response <---- Server <----query result---- Database

I hope this helps

Read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model